# h2 set background color and underline

Tags: css

i need help with this CSS problem. I want to style `<h2>` element in a way that the background color only applies to the text, and also a border-bottom.

Here is the preview.

[image: Here is the preview.]

I could have done this my self, its not that difficult but the problem is that i cant add extra elements (like `<span>` tag) inside the `<h2>` tag. so i'm looking for a pure css way to that type of styling.

CSS Code:

```
h2 {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font: 700 16px Open Sans;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(136, 136, 136);
}
```

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: post some of your CSS, you can use pseudo classes :before or :After to accomplish this

Comment: Is the "preview" what you hope to accomplish, or the problem as it stands now?

Comment: @Alexander Lozada yeah, you got me :D

Comment: @yaqoob if you **cannot** change the HTML, can you use JS?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my first priority (or need) is to be done with CSS. The `:after` thingy can do that, but i don't know how. If css wont work then i'll try jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/Ukinupa/3/edit)***

```
h2{
  font: normal normal normal 20px/1 Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;

  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px 15px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
h2:after{ /* the line under H2 */
  left:0px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  margin-top:2px;
  content: " ";
  background:#000;
}
```

---

You can try using `:first-line` pseudo: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/Ukinupa/2/edit)

```
h2{
  font: normal normal normal 20px/1 Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
h2:first-line{
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

But you cannot (AFAIK) set padding to `:first-line`

---

**If you can use jQuery** ***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/Ukinupa/4/edit)***

jQ:

```
$('h2').wrapInner("<span />");
```

CSS:

```
h2{
  font: normal normal normal 20px/1 Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
h2 span{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: But you can't have a padding around the text can you?

Comment: @putvande now I'm creating an example where you can!

Comment: Just add `padding-left: 10px;` and it will be padded :-P

Comment: @putvande added an example. I think it's the only way (without JS).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ok i have tried your Updated Code. The `border-bottom` is going on left side of the page, (because of `left:0;` i guess) so i removed it and now the text block with background area is absolute on the left side. its ok, but i need to margin it from left (just like in example screenshot)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ok i'll go with the jQuery solution, but the `<h2>` elements are above the fold and the styling doesn't applies as the page loads, first it shows without the `background` then after 2,3 seconds it changes the style. Although your provided jQuery+CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that with `:after` pseudo-element:

```
h2 {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font: 700 16px Open Sans;
    margin: 0px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(136, 136, 136);
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    margin-top:10px; /*Apply same value of padding-bottom*
}
```

The line maked with the `:after` element just depend on the parent's `h2` width since the `h2` isn't the relative for the absolute position.

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgknp/)**

Comment: Does the first `color: rgb(0, 0, 0);` have any effect? Or is it just leftover trash?

Comment: @PhilPerry doesn't have any effect .. is override by the other I don't see the duplicity my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Use `:after`:

```
h2 { 
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: black;
    left: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H67CF/1/)

Comment: than try with the text: `<h2>Popular now totally long text</h2>`

Comment: It is not dynamically no, but I don't think you can without adding another element.

Comment: Hi, i tried your css code the width of black background is fixed on all `<h2>` elements, can't they be dynamic (only applies to text area)

Comment: No it can't be dynamically this way.