# Why can't my CSS style work on the first line?

Tags: html, css

```css
<style  type="text/css">
h2{background:gray;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
h3{background:blue;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
p{background:red;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Link to external style sheet</title>
 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link-css1.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>This is the H2 demo</h2>

 <h3>This is the H3 demo</h3>

 <p>This is the p demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result?
IE [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osWtG.jpg)

**why my css style doesn't work on the first line?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h2 set background color and underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317112/h2-set-background-color-and-underline)

Comment: You don't have to add <style> in .css files

Comment: snippet adjusted. Works fine now

Comment: @Gerard Your edit defeats the purpose of the question as it was the cause of the error. The question now makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not sure you should have edited the post, because now the question is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you remove the style tags from the CSS. They shouldn't be there unless you are adding CSS in your HTML, like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Link to external style sheet</title>
  <style>
    h2 {
      background: gray;
      font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
      font-size: 50px
    }
    
    h3 {
      background: blue;
      font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
      font-size: 50px
    }
    
    p {
      background: red;
      font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
      font-size: 50px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>This is the H2 demo</h2>
  <h3>This is the H3 demo</h3>
  <p>This is the p demo</p>
</body>

</html>
```

But as you have a stylesheet link, you obviously don't need `<style>` tags.

```css
h2 {
  background: gray;
  font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
  font-size: 50px
}

h3 {
  background: blue;
  font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
  font-size: 50px
}

p {
  background: red;
  font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
  font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Link to external style sheet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link-css1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>This is the H2 demo</h2>
  <h3>This is the H3 demo</h3>
  <p>This is the p demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OOOOO！thank u! I just didn't check the compiler plug-in ，emmet Automatic state. and, I'm a new a newbie really 。   You are the most patient for me.

Comment: @handeepblue Your'e welcome. If you're happy with my answer, remember to accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `<style>` tags in your CSS file. You only need to use that if you're including CSS in HTML. Those tags will be invalid in a CSS file, and will break the rule that comes after them.

```css
h2{background:gray;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
h3{background:blue;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
p{background:red;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Link to external style sheet</title>
 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link-css1.css">
 <!-- this is how you would include styles in HTML, and when you need to use the <style> tag
 <style>
  h2{background:gray;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
  h3{background:blue;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
  p{background:red;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px}
 </style>
 -->
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>This is the H2 demo</h2>

 <h3>This is the H3 demo</h3>

 <p>This is the p demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OOOOO！thank u! I just didn't check the compiler plug-in ，emmet Automatic state.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using external file as CSS, then not needed put the css code inside style tag.

Comment: OOOOO！thank u! I just didn't check the compiler plug-in ，emmet Automatic state. and, I'm a new a newbie really 。

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your h3 and p tags got the color, but try closing all your declarations with a semicolon. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

```
h2{background:gray;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";font-size:50px;}
```

Yes the ; is necessary or it might not get the styles.